# Python automation for Microsoft Visio application (pywin32 module)

Tags: python, automation, pywin32, win32com, visio

I want to automate Microsoft Visio Application using Python language(By the way I've been learning python for 6 months).
I searched this topic a lot on the internet, and I found out that I can succeed using win32com(pywin32) module; however, win32com(pywin32) has almost no documentation.
Just for information, while searching, I learned important concepts like COM.

Moreover, I found some scripts to print out methods, however, there is no documentation or clear examples about how to use them.

The script that I found for listing methods:

```
from inspect import getmembers
import win32com.client


def print_members(obj, obj_name="Visio.Application"):
    """Print members of given COM object"""
    try:
        fields = list(obj._prop_map_get_.keys())
    except AttributeError:
        print("Object has no attribute '_prop_map_get_'")
        print("Check if the initial COM object was created with"
              "'win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()'")
        raise
    methods = [m[0] for m in getmembers(obj) if (not m[0].startswith("_")
                                                 and "clsid" not in m[0].lower())]

    if len(fields) + len(methods) > 0:
        print("Members of '{}' ({}):".format(obj_name, obj))
    else:
        raise ValueError("Object has no members to print")

    print("\tFields:")
    if fields:
        for field in fields:
            print(f"\t\t{field}")
    else:
        print("\t\tObject has no fields to print")

    print("\tMethods:")
    if methods:
        for method in methods:
            print(f"\t\t{method}")
    else:
        print("\t\tObject has no methods to print")


print_members(win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Visio.Application"))
```

My aim is to load some templates in Visio and modify them by adding new connections / adding some shapes / deleting shapes comes from template. Then save the Visio document, and I want to make every process happen in the background(During run, nothing will be shown on screen. At the end, I want to see saved files.).

How can I learn this and go further? I'm open to any ideas, **I have great desire to learn Visio automation using Python**. I would be very appreciated if any experienced guys guide me.

Comment: The reason you can't find documentation is probably because you are looking in the wrong place. `win32com` gives you back a thin Python wrapper around a COM server *provided by the application*. The documentation for the Visio object model is at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/visio/object-model. Be aware that the objects you get back are VBA objects in a thin Python wrapper and so don't always behave like Python objects, and the documentation assumes you are writing in VBA not Python.

Comment: @BoarGules thanks for quick reply. I was at the very wrong place.  So, what I understand from your provided page and you is, all Visio documentation is created for VBA and **win32com** creates  COM objects which behaves like VBA objects.

Comment: That's it. Which can mean that it's not always obvious how to write Python to do what the VBA examples show.

Comment: @BoarGules Once again, thanks a lot.  I'm a really python enthusiast but I think it's better to improve a program using VBA because of the Visio itself. What do you think or what do you suggest?